# How can I bulk-remove Github notifications for pull requests that have been merged?

Tags: github, notifications, pull-request

I'm going through my Github notifications (https://github.com/notifications) and have a ton of unread notifications related to pull requests that have been merged already.

I would like to be able to select all those notifications (for pull requests that have been merged) and then delete them. That way I can focus on new notifications for PRs of other status.

Note: this is different from viewing all PRs that have been merged; that is underneath the "Pull requests" tab. I'm referring here to the notifications section of Github.

Right now it seems like I can only filter my notifications to see if the notification is related to a PR:

`is:issue-or-pull-request`

I would like to expect a way to filter based on the PR status as well. Any tips appreciated!